# SSHFS mount does not work on startup using fstab

Tags: server, fstab, sshfs

While I am able to mount a folder from a remote server using `mount folder` the entry in `fstab` is giving `Connection reset by peer`:

I have the following in my fstab

```
sshfs#username@remote:/folder/ folder fuse defaults,idmap=user 0 0
```

I have also configure trusted relationship between the remote server and the origin using public keys. and I am able to do `ssh remote` and authenticate without using a password.

Also, If I log in on the origin machine and use:

```
mount folder
```

the folder mounts succesfully.

Any suggestions?

Origin distro : 12.04 Remote server: 11.10

Answer (score 1):

sshfs needs a network connection. Maybe it is not set up at the time the `ftsab` mounts are executed. Never had problems with cable network but if I use wifi I have to mount it manually too. You also should add the `_netdev` parameter to your `fstab`. Otherwise the mount is waiting for a timeout and it will slow down your boot process.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like your missing the -o identifyfile=

```
sshfs#username@remote:/folder/ folder -o identityfile=~/yourkeyfile  fuse defaults,idmap=user 0 0
```

also keep in mind your home dir will not be decrypted by this point so what I do is make a read only folder /keys for my keys

also, what I did to make things stupid simple was added sshfs to a python script and then in cron I put:

```
@reboot <username> /usr/bin/python /scripts/mounttheserver.py >> /scripts/servermount.log
```

Here is the python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import os

os.system ("sshfs -o identityfile=<KEYFILE> <USERNAME>@<ADDRESS>:/storage /storage")
```

just make sure you +x it!